# ViewPager into ListView with RadioButton to Detect Pagination

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a ListView with ViewPager on each rowItem.I also managed to create radioButtons on each RowItem where radiobutton==no. of Picture in ViewPager.

MY question is When I scroll the ViewPager on FirstRow it show me correct change of RadioButton.BUt When I change the Second Row it Change Again the First RowItem RadioButton

My Dynamic RadioButton......

```
public void addRadio(RadioGroup radiogrp){

    for(int i=0;i<pageCount;i++){

        radiobtn=new RadioButton(context);
        radiobtn.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.radio_3);
        radiobtn.setFocusable(true);
        radiobtn.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        radiobtn.setAlpha(0.5f);
        radiobtn.setClickable(false);
        radiobtn.setId(i);
        radiogrp.addView(radiobtn,i);

    }
}
```

ViewPager Change Listner

```
      holder.vPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.d("pos", ""+position);
            for(int i=0;i<integer.length;i++){
            holder.radiogrp.getChildAt(integer.length-(i+1)).setAlpha(0.5f);
            }                   
            holder.radiogrp.getChildAt(position).setAlpha(1.0f);

            Log.d("pos", ""+position+"");   
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Any Answer Appreciated...Thks

Comment: see this https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to and now check you will come to know

```
public void addRadio(RadioGroup radiogrp){

    for(int i=0;i<pageCount;i++){

        radiobtn=new RadioButton(context);
        radiobtn.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.radio_3);

        radiobtn.setAlpha(0.5f);

        radiobtn.setId(i);
        radiogrp.addView(radiobtn,i);

    }
}
```

Good Luck..